# how to scale a user provided image across multiple devices

Tags: android, ios, image

I am having a problem on how to display user provided images to other users across different devices. For example, I have multiple copies of varying sizes for the same image for my app. These are images I created during development and are part of the app which can support different sized screens. Inside of my app though users can upload a picture of themselves. Obviously now I do not have control of the dimensions of this image. Some users may have new fancy phones which produce very high quality pictures while other users may have not so great phones and produce lower quality images. As well, with user uploaded pictures there is only one image upload. What is the best practice to display these images across various devices. So a user who took a picture on their new iphone 6 will appear nicely on a smaller 3 year old android device as well as a photo taken on a smaller 3 year old android device will appear nicely on an iphone 6?

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html provides information on how to control images inside of android if I the developer have control of the images, but what if I don't? What if I receive a low quality image from a user, what is the best practice to show it nicely on an ipad for instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can read those guide:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

When receive your image, you can read its size and decide the scale size it base on user device. (But a small image still looks nasty on a big screen).

Beside, I think you can use other download library like Picasso or Glide to support download and decode image.

Hope this helps.